# import data from excel with foreign key in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am using EF Database first edmx. I have a mode two model classes

1. Country
2. States

**COUNTRIES**

```
public int COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
public string COUNTRY_CODE { get; set; }
public string COUNTRY_NAME { get; set; }
```

**STATES**

```
public int STATE_ID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> COUNTRY_ID { internal get; set; }
public string STATE_CODE { get; set; }
public string STATE_NAME { get; set; }
```

I have imported COUNTRIES data from excel and save into SQL Database. Now I want to do the same for STATES, but it is having a foreign key COUNTRY_ID reference COUNTRIES. The excel sheet is having Country as string, but my application need to ckeck the COUNTRIES model class for the availability of the COUNTRY_NAME, and convert the COUNTRY_NAME in STATES Class to the related COUNTRY_ID in COUNTRIES class.
Please How do I do this.
This is my controller code that I already have

```
        public ActionResult ImportStatesExcel(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
    {
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        var bodsList = new List<STATES>();
        if (FileUpload != null)
        {
            // tdata.ExecuteCommand("truncate table OtherCompanyAssets");  
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["FileUpload"];
            if (true)//FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
                {
                    var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                    // if(currentSheet.Count)
                    var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                    var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                    {
                        var bod = new STATES();
                        bod.STATE_CODE = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Text;//.ToString().Trim();
                        bod.STATE_NAME = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Text;//.ToString().Trim();
                bod.COUNTRY_ID = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Text;//.ToString().Trim();


                        // bod.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION = DateTime.Now;
                        bod.ACTION_STATUS = 0;
                        bod.CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now;
                        bodsList.Add(bod);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var item in bodsList)
                {
                    _countriesService.AddCountry(item);
                }
                //_boardofdirectorService.AddBoardOfDirector(bod);
                //return View("Index");
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                //alert message for invalid file format  
                data.Add("<ul>");
                data.Add("<li>Only Excel file format is allowed</li>");
                data.Add("</ul>");
                data.ToArray();
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            data.Add("<ul>");
            if (FileUpload == null) data.Add("<li>Please choose Excel file</li>");
            data.Add("</ul>");
            data.ToArray();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might read all the country names and it's Ids and store it in a dictionary first. When you are processing each row in the spreadsheet, get the country id by the country name and use it for saving.

```
var countryDict=  db.Countries.ToDictionary(f => f.COUNTRY_NAME, x => x.COUNTRY_ID );

for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
{
    var bod = new STATES();
    bod.STATE_CODE = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Text;//.ToString().Trim();
    bod.STATE_NAME = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Text;//.ToString().Trim();
    var countryName = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Text;//.ToString().Trim();
    //It is a good idea to trim (if not null) to avoid whitespaces
    if (countryDict.ContainsKey(countryName)==false)
    {
       throw new ArgumentException("Invalid country");
    }
    bod.COUNTRY_ID= countryDict[countryName];

    // bod.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION = DateTime.Now;
    bod.ACTION_STATUS = 0;
    bod.CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now;
    bodsList.Add(bod);
}
```

Currently the above code will throw an exception when it finds a country name which does not exist in our dictionary as a key. You can change it to just ignore saving that bad record as needed. Dictionary's `TryGetValue` method will be useful.

Comment: I am using it but I get  this exception  System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.